# Resources about Shen Castan algorithm

Tags: algorithm, edge-detection

I have started some simple project about Text Detection in images. And one of steps in solving this problem is implementation of Edge detector. I wanted to implement Shen Castan, because it gives better results with noisy images. Problem is that I cannot find anywhere some usefull resources about this algorithm. Does anyone knows how Shan Castan works ? Or have some article about this ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This describes both the Canny and Shen-Castan methods: http://www.comput-vision.net/Computer.vision-Advanced.Edge/

Comment: Link seems to be dead?

Answer (score 2):

It's quite expensive, but if you're serious about edge detection, I'd highly recommended the book [Algorithms for Image Processing and Computer Vision](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471140562). It's a techniques cookbook, and also comes with a CD of C source code implementations. [Here's a review](http://www.amazon.com/review/R2D98Y5XNNWM4P/) that specifically mentions the Canny and Shen-Castan techniques.